# Render a template based on the resolve in $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, resolve

Consider this code:

```
bank.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('main.bank', {
      url: '/',
      controller: 'BankCtrl',
      resolve: {
        money: function(bankResource) {
          return bankResource.getMoney();
      },
      templateUrl: 'bank/bank.html'
    });
});
```

Above I render the `bank.html` template once resolve is finished executing.

**I want to** render a specific template depending on what is returned from my `money` function.

Example:

if `money` returns an object with items, render `bank.html`

if `money` returns an empty object, then return `empty-bank.html`

How can I achieve this within my $stateProvider? Or would it even make more sense for it to be in a directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `resolve` code to parent controller, create two child routes one for each of `bank.html` and `empty-bank.html` and route based on the result of resolve, something like this -

```
.state('main', {
  url: '/',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  resolve: {
    money: function(bankResource) {
      return bankResource.getMoney();
  }
})
.state('main.bank', {
  url: '/blank',
  controller: 'BankCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'bank/bank.html'
})
.state('main.emptybank', {
  url: '/emptyblank',
  controller: 'EmptyBankCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'bank/empty-bank.html'
});
```

Inject the result of resolve into your controller and change state based on the output.

Comment: If I refresh the page, this solution no longer works. Changing the state in my controller does not seem to work because the controller only gets instantiated once. When I refresh the page, the controller does not get called again, and therefore no 'change state' logic is called and the view becomes blank.

Comment: If you refresh the page, the parent controller is always called first and resolve code is re-executed.

Answer (score 1):

In the index.html of your main state, switch views based on the money variable. E.a.:

```
.state('main', {
  url: '/',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
```

In your MainCtrl set a variable based on the output of your function:

```
$scope.money = "bank"
```

or

```
$scope.money = "emptybank"
```

Then in your index.html call a view:

```
<div ng-view="{{$scope.money}}"></div>
```

In your router:

```
.state('main.bank', {
  url: '/bank',
  views: {
     bank: {
    controller: 'BankCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'bank/bank.html'
    },
    emptybank: {
    controller: 'EmptyBankCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'bank/emptybank.html'
    }
  }
})
```

Sorry in advance for any syntax errors. Typed it from head on my mobile phone.

But this should fix your problem and in the progress make it more "Angularesque" :-)